# Tagged Pdf value from Adobe's document properties using iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

In Adobe when we press ctrl+d it shows properties of the pdf. From that Document properties how to get `taggedpdf` value using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 0):

The **StructTreeRoot** is a mandatory element for a Tagged PDF:

```
PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
PdfObject structTreeRoot = root.Get(PdfName.STRUCTTREEROOT);
```

If `structTreeRoot` equals `null`, then your PDF isn't tagged.

Additionally, you need to check for the **MarkInfo** property.

```
PdfDictionary markInfo = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.MARKINFO);
```

This `markInfo` dictionary may not be null, it needs a **Marked** entry. The value of this entry needs to be a `Boolean` and it needs to be `true`.

In answer to your comment falsely claiming that some of the PDFs you tested are valid Tagged PDF, see the following screenshots:

[image: PDF 1]
[image: PDF 2]
[image: PDF 3]

To the left, you can see the internal object tree of the documents you shared. As you can see, the documents have a `StructTreeRoot`, but the value of `MarkInfo` is `false`.

To the right, you can see the documents opened in Adobe Reader. In all three cases, the Document Properties has an entry that says: Tagged PDF: No.

Beats me why you'd claim otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Bruno..How to find pdf version, Image or text pdf,number of pages from the propertiies?

Comment: Image or text PDF: very difficult. The best way is to parse the pages with the parser classes. If no text is found, chances are you only have images. Number of pages: that's a no-brainer: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/PageInformation.cs (Please don't abuse the comment section to ask follow-up questions. It's hard to answer in a comment window. Also don't use SO as a replacement for reading the documentation.)

Comment: The above solution will not work in some PDF.can any one have any other idea or solution???

Comment: Why wouldn't this work in some PDFs? Which type of PDFs are you talking about?

Comment: The pdf was tagged pdf and it having the value 'yes'.But the above concept doesn't render the value.that's y i am asking the alternate solution if any..

Comment: i have placed 3 sample pdf in below link, kindly check this and do the needful                                          https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_nzYHWVJJ7KVTBlSGlRUEdMOVk&usp=sharing

Comment: I've tested your three documents. None of them qualifies as Tagged PDF according to Adobe Reader; I've looked inside the files using iText, and iText tells me the value of MarkInfo is false, which is consistent with what Adobe Reader tells us. In other words: my answer was correct. Maybe you've implemented my answer incorrectly, or you're just pulling my leg when you say iText has different results than Adobe Reader.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response bruno..i will not say that your answer was wrong..i just explain my problem and expecting your suggestion..The above pdf showing taggedpdf=No.But in our application it returns yes..that is the problem..don't mistaken me for asking this..How to view that mark info value?

Comment: Er... So Adobe Reader says you don't have Tagged PDF, but your applications says it's Tagged PDF. Might I ask what software you're using? I used iText RUPS to look inside the PDF, but you can get that value using the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot bruno..it was working great..I am a newbie to this type of itext manipulation..i learned a lot from your solution..thank u so much